# Function not working after push() elements in html file

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to create a to do list that will add elements typed in `<input type="text">` and delete when clicked on button with class `.delete`. When ever I push elements in an array. And `innerHTML` it in html page, the delete button stops working. The delete button works for elements that are written into Html code. If someone can help me I will be very thankful.
`

```js
    const itemsLIst = document.querySelector('.item-list'); // where we want to add our list
    const addText = document.querySelector('.submit');     // add button
    let deleteText = document.querySelectorAll('.delete');  // delete button
    // const list = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('items')) || [];
    let list = [];

    function addItem(e) {
    let text = document.querySelector('.input_bar').value; //text typed in input bar
    if (text.length != 0) {
    list.push(`<div>
        <p>${text}</p>
        <button class="delete" onclick='deleteItem'></button>
        <button class="edit">Edit</button>
        </div><hr>`);
        itemsLIst.innerHTML = list.join('');
        text = '0';
        document.getElementById("myText").value = "";
    } else {
        return;
    }
    }

    function deleteItem(e) {
        this.parentElement.style.display = 'none';
    }

    for (var i = 0 ; i < deleteText.length; i++) {
       deleteText[i].addEventListener('click', deleteItem);
    }

    addText.addEventListener('click', addItem);
```

```css
       <style>
                body {
                    width: 100%;
                    height: 100vh;
                    background-color: rgb(115, 115, 197);
                    margin: 0;
                    padding: 0;
                    position: relative;
                }
                .container {
                    width:50%;
                    height:70%;
                    position: absolute;
                    background-color: rgb(241, 241, 241);
                    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
                    border-bottom-left-radius: 25px;
                    border-bottom-right-radius: 25px;
                    top: 50%;
                    left: 50%;
                    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
                    overflow-y: scroll;

                }
                .heading {
                    width: 100%;
                    height: 122px;
                    background-color: #5B45B9;
                    display: flex;
                    align-items: center;
                    justify-content: center; 
                }
                .heading h1 {
                    color: white;
                    font-size: 40px;
                }
                .item-list {
                    width: 100%;
                    padding: 0 0 30px 0;
                }
                .item-list div {
                    width: auto;
                    height: 60px;
                }
                
                p {
                    width: 60%;
                    float: left;
                    font-size: 25px;
                    padding-left: 30px;
                    margin-top: 12px ;
                }
                .item-list button {
                    width: 60px;
                    height: 60px;
                    font-size: 18px;
                    float: right;
                }
                .delete {
                    font-size: 30px;
                    color: red;
                }
                .input_form {
                    width: 100%;
                    padding: 30px 0 30px 0;
                    position: absolute;
                    bottom: 0;
                    text-align: center;
                }
                .input_form .input_bar {
                    width: 80%;
                    height: 50px;
                    font-size: 18px;
                    border: none;
                }
                .input_form button {
                    width: 10%;
                    height: 50px;
                    float: right;
                    margin-right: 30px;
                }
            </style>
```

```html
    <html>
        <head>
         
        </head>
        <body>
            <div class="container">
                <div class="heading">
                    <h1>TO-DO LIST</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="item-list">
                    <div>
                        <p>TEEXT2</p>
                        <button class="delete"></button>
                        <button class="edit">Edit</button>
                    </div>
                    <div>
                        <p>TEEXT1</p>
                        <button class="delete"></button>
                        <button class="edit">Edit</button>
                    </div>
                    
                    <div>
                        <p>TEEXT3</p>
                        <button class="delete"></button>
                        <button class="edit">Edit</button>
                    </div>

                    <div>
                        <p>TEEXT4</p>
                        <button class="delete"></button>
                        <button class="edit">Edit</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="input_form">
                    <input type="text" class="input_bar" id="myText" placeholder="Add ITEM">
                    <button class="submit">+ADD ITEM</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

```
<button class="delete"></button>
                    <button class="edit">Edit</button>
                </div>
                <div>
                    <p>TEEXT1</p>
                    <button class="delete"></button>
                    <button class="edit">Edit</button>
                </div>
                
                <div>
                    <p>TEEXT3</p>
                    <button class="delete"></button>
                    <button class="edit">Edit</button>
                </div>

                <div>
                    <p>TEEXT4</p>
                    <button class="delete"></button>
                    <button class="edit">Edit</button>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="input_form">
                <input type="text" class="input_bar" id="myText" placeholder="Add ITEM">
                <button class="submit">+ADD ITEM</button>
            </div>
            <script src="script.js"></script>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>`
```

Comment: here while adding elements itself will replace your data, and will appear newly adding data, you have to use localStorage() at least to handle data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually only trigger DOM "original" delete button (button loaded with your HTML code) with the line :

```
let deleteText = document.querySelectorAll('.delete');  // delete button
```

Your others .delete are loaded after the first DOM loading and are not even listed in "deleteText" array !
You have to refresh deleteText every time you add a new item. Something like :

```
    const itemsLIst = document.querySelector('.item-list'); // where we want to add our list
    const addText = document.querySelector('.submit');     // add button
    let deleteText = document.querySelectorAll('.delete');  // delete button
    // const list = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('items')) || [];
    let list = [];
    
    function addItem(e) {
        let text = document.querySelector('.input_bar').value; //text typed in input bar
        if (text.length != 0) {
            list.push(`<div>
                <p>${text}</p>
                <button class="delete" onclick='deleteItem'></button>
                <button class="edit">Edit</button>
                </div><hr>`);
            itemsLIst.innerHTML = list.join('');
            text = '0';
            document.getElementById("myText").value = "";
        } else {
            return;
        }
    
    
    }
    
    function deleteItem(e) {
        this.parentElement.style.display = 'none';
    }
    
    function triggerDeleteButton(){
    
        deleteText = document.querySelectorAll('.delete');  // delete button
    
        for (var i = 0 ; i < deleteText.length; i++) {
            deleteText[i].addEventListener('click', deleteItem);
        }
    }
    
    addText.addEventListener('click', function(){
addItem() ;
triggerDeleteButton() ;
}
);
```

Comment: Thanx a lot for your help. :)

Answer (score 0):

Without refreshing, you can add and edit data by using local storage
For example, like below, you can try once!

```
    <script>
    let customerData  = [];
    // Inserting new customer record into local storage
    function insert() {
        let company  = document.getElementById("company").value;

        let obj = {company};
        customerData.push(obj);
        synData(customerData);
        let customerDetails = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("customerString"));
        clearFileds();
        displayelements(customerDetails);
    }

    function displayelements(customerDetails) {
        let html = "<table id='customer_data' border='1'><tr><th>Sl No</th><th>Company</th><th>Delete</th></tr>";
        if(customerDetails == '') {
            html+="<tr>No record found!</tr>";
        } else {
            customerDetails.map((values, index) => {
                html+="<tr id='row_data'>";
                html+="<td>"+index+"</td>";
                html+="<td>"+values.company+"</td>";
                html+="<td onclick='deleteRow(" + index + ")'>Delete</td>";
                html+="</tr>";

             } )
        }
        html+="</table>";
        document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = html;
        clearFileds();
    }

    // Delete the specific customer record from local storage
    function deleteRow(deleteKey) {
        let customerDetails = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("customerString"));
        customerDetails.map((values, index) => {
            if (index == deleteKey) {
                customerDetails.splice(index, 1);
           }
        })
        customerData = customerDetails;
        synData(customerDetails);
        displayelements(customerDetails);
    }


    // Clearing the form input field data
    function clearFileds() {
        document.getElementById("company").value = '';
    }


    // Updating local storage data
    function synData(customerDetails) {
        localStorage.setItem('customerString', JSON.stringify(customerDetails));
    }



</script>

<html>
<head>
<title>Save</title>
</head>
    <script ></script>
    <body id="format_background">
      <div id="customerAction" >
        <h1>Customer data</h1>
        <label>Company Name </label>
        <input id="company" type="text" />
        <button type="button" value="Save&Show" onclick="insert()" id="insert">Save</button>
      </div>
      <div id="display"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```